# Dynamics CRM 2016: JavaScript causes JSON Parse Error

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest, dynamics-crm-2015

I am trying to get the price of a product in Dynamics CRM 2016, by javascript on the onChange event for the product. This is on a custom entity I have created and is using the pricelistid and the productid.

When I use the same javascript in the console on Chrome i can get the data out but when it is executed by the CRM form I get an error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse ()

The code is:

```
var pricelevelid = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("sg_pricelistid").getValue()[0].id;
pricelevelid = pricelevelid.replace(/[{}]/g, "");

var productdata = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("sg_productid").getValue();
if (productdata != null)
        {
        console.log("going into productdata loop");
        productid = productdata[0].id;
        productid = productid.replace(/[{}]/g, "");

        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("GET", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v8.0/productpricelevels?$select=amount,_pricelevelid_value,_productid_value,productpricelevelid&$filter=_pricelevelid_value eq " + pricelevelid + " and  _productid_value eq " + productid + "", true);
        req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
        req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
        req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState === 4) {
                req.onreadystatechange = null;
                if (this.status === 200) {
                  var results = JSON.parse(this.response);
                        for (var i = 0; i < results.value.length; i++) {
                            var amount = results.value[i]["amount"];
                            var amount_formatted = results.value[i]["amount@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"];
                        }
                } else {
                    Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
                }
            }
        };
        req.send();

        data = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
        var amount = data.value[0]["amount"];
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("sg_unitprice").setValue(amount);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are performing an asynchronous request and then attempting to parse the response, before it has been set to anything.

This happens at the bottom of your code block at `data = JSON.parse(req.responseText)`, right after you send the request.

All code that relies on the response should be executed in the `req.onreadystatechange` callback function.